# Visual Studio page colors problems

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, razor, text, colors

I cannot realize how is this possible. Two different index pages but one cannot working with scripts and css styles. Another pages works fine. I already did factory reset **Import and export settings**

Thank you

With color:

[image: With color]

Without color:

[image: Without color]

Comment: Ok. there must be problem inside body section. When I remove all body content all colors inside <css> and <scripts> display properly

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem. When I removed highlighted row change colors display properly

Solution:

[image: SOLUTION]